# Is it possible to overload javax validation annotations to read in multiple data types?

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I'm using custom validations from [javax.validator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html); @Min, @Max. I've made custom annotations though. Is there a way to use a single annotation for multiple datatypes?

If my annotation is roughly:

```
    @Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValidator.class)
    @Documented
    public @interface CustomAnnotation{ /* Annotation code */ }
```

and my validator is roughly:

```
    public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomAnnotation, int> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(CustomAnnoation constraintAnnotation) { /* Init Code */ }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(int object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) { /* isValid Code */ }
    }
```

This would make an annotation that only accepts int inputs. How could I overload the annotation to also accept, say doubles?

Answer (score 0):

You created class with isValid(..) method, it doesn't have anything to do with annotations.
I understand, that you want to create annotation as a place of discovery of a validator class, if yes, just overload isValid(..) method with different types an it will work.

Comment: I've already tried this, and it does not work. The implement pulls in <AnnotationFile, Datatype> and that Datatype is what isValid requires. If I tried switching isValid to pull a double instead of an int, it would error out saying that CustomValidator is not abstract and requires and overridden isValid method.

Comment: But how did you manage to make it work with <CustomAnnotation, int> in a first place? Java parametrised types don't allow primitives. I don't know what do you want to validate there, but you could for instance do <CustomAnnotation, Number> and inside isValid(..) method call object.doubleValue().

Comment: Apologies, in my code I'm actually using Integer rather than int. I will try using Number instead of Integer or Double. I'd like this to work for arrays as well though, such as private Integer[] IntegerArray. Would I still need a separate annotation/validator for arrays if your method works?

Comment: But most important thing here is to think about method logic. Does it make sense to put validation for those types (numbers and arrays) together? You can always use Number[] or Double[] as your type parameter and for single numbers create an array with single element: new Integer[] {1};

Comment: It does make sense since they're validating the same thing. An array would just be validating multiples at one time. I cannot just make an array validator and then make all of my variables arrays. The validator is being created for a premade Form of which I can't change any variables.

Comment: As well, I want to do this for multiple data types--not just int/doubles--which is why I'm asking if it's possible to overload and not just sneak past it for a specific instance.

Comment: Ok, but what is your goal here, what kind of validation do you want to perform, because my previous question about sense is valid. We started from numbers, but you say you want to validate other types, do you want to have a all-in-one validator that validates dates, numbers, addresses and email address?

Comment: You can do <CustomAnnotation, Object> and inside of CustomValidator  go with overloading isValid(..) with whatever you need to check, late binding should do the trick.

Comment: One example is to validate that a given number is within certain bounds (0 - 100). The previous developer, however, stored some numbers as int, some as double, and some as string (that get cast as to int later). I need to be able to run the same check on each of these types, so rather than making 3 different annotations/validators, I'd rather have 1 annotation/validator overloaded to work for each type. I do not need one validator to work for ALL types, but I would like some to work for multiples. Thank you for the help so far, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering the answer to this question - it is just possible to pass an array of validators to the interface and each validator will implement different data type.

for example if we make a custom @Max annotation :

```
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomMaxLongValidator.class, CustomMaxIntValidator.class, CustomMaxShortValidator.class})
public @interface CustomMax {
    /**
     * @return value the element must be lower or equal to
     */
    long value();

    String message() default "Custom Max Validation error";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

pay attention it is validated by 3 validator classes

```
validatedBy = {CustomMaxLongValidator.class, CustomMaxIntValidator.class, CustomMaxShortValidator.class}
```

Each class will have it's own type

```
public class CustomMaxIntValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomMax, Integer>
public class CustomMaxShortValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomMax, Short>
public class CustomMaxLongValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomMax, Long>
```

Hope that helps!